# Booting DragonFly BSD with GRUB2Win fails

Tags: grub2

After manually adding `insmod part_dfly` in GRUB.cfg, partition search by file does find loader. Then, rather than Dragonfly booting, only blank screen appears. GRUB has an elf.mod so the reason is other than the kernel not being PE32+.

Comment: Wrongly migrated as GRUB2Win is about Windows, and UEFI boot is administrators problem, as it is arising well before *nix boots up.